# Why it loads neg samples(40*40) too slowly when I using opencv_traincascade.exe?

Tags: opencv

Why it loads neg samples(40*40) too slowly when I using opencv_traincascade.exe? It may toke 1-2 minutes to load a neg samples.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not just loading a single negative sample within that time, it is the collection of negative samples that are still classified as positive samples, so the new training stage can go and find features that distinguish your positive samples from those negative samples. With each stage, your classifier gets better and better and more negative samples are already classified correctly, the harder it gets to find negative samples that are usable in that training stage. After enough negative samples are collected, you'll see a value (acceptanceRatio) which shows you the rate of usable negative samples found.

For example, here is a stage preparation from a training I had once:

[image]

The acceptance ratio is 3.03652e-005 which means the negative samples collection had to test in average 32932.4 negative samples to find a single USABLE negative sample. Yes, this takes a long time (especially if the classifier gets more "complicated"). The more different negative sample pictures you use, typically the easier it gets to find usable samples. If you've chosen for example max false alarm rate of 0.5, in theory you'll have to double the number of negative images tested in each stage. This is also an indicator of how well your training is working. If the acceptance ratio doesn't go down in each stage, the training is probably not working well, it does not look like it is generalizing well.